# The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I created a service to be host in sharepoint

Here's the svc code behind:

```
   [ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class MyService: IMyService
    {
        public bool AddNewItem(string id, string msg)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public string GetAllItems(string id)
        {
            return "test";
        }
    }
```

Here's the interface

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetAllItems/{id}",
          ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetAllItems(string id);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/AddNewItem",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    bool AddNewItem(string id, string msg);
}
```

And here's the web.config of the svc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyService.ISAPI.ServiceBehaviour" name ="MyService.MyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="MyService.ISAPI.IMyService">

        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />

      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name ="MyService.ISAPI.ServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Here's the app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="MyService.MyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyService.ISAPI.IMyService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/MyService/MyService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

When I tried accessing the svc through the browser in this link `www.mySharepoint.com/_vti_bin/MyService.svc/GetAllItems/1`, the below error occurs:

> The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to
>   a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be
>   because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between
>   sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender
>   and the receiver. Check that sender and receiver have the same
>   contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g.
>   Message, Transport, None).

What is the problem?

I think it's weird to have app.config and web.config at the same time, should I merge the config into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, I was because I have to modify the sharepoint's web.config instead of creating one in the project.

In the sharepoint's web.config, I specified the endpoint

```
    <service behaviorConfiguration="MyService.ISAPI.ServiceBehaviour" name ="MyService.MyService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
                      contract="MyService.ISAPI.IMyService">

            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />

  </service>
```

Now the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

Assign the same value as in endpoint to the "Namespace" parameter of ServiceContract attribute of the Service Class/interface