# C# WCF receives empty model from XML

Tags: c#, wcf

We have a model in service

```
  [XmlRoot(ElementName = "CanonicalizationMethod")]
    public class CanonicalizationMethod
    {

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Algorithm")]
        public string Algorithm { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "SignatureMethod")]
    public class SignatureMethod
    {

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Algorithm")]
        public string Algorithm { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Transform")]
    public class Transform
    {

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Algorithm")]
        public string Algorithm { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Transforms")]
    public class Transforms
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Transform")]
        public Transform Transform { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DigestMethod")]
    public class DigestMethod
    {

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Algorithm")]
        public string Algorithm { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Reference")]
    public class Reference
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Transforms")]
        public Transforms Transforms { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DigestMethod")]
        public DigestMethod DigestMethod { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DigestValue")]
        public string DigestValue { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "URI")]
        public string URI { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "SignedInfo")]
    public class SignedInfo
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "CanonicalizationMethod")]
        public CanonicalizationMethod CanonicalizationMethod { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SignatureMethod")]
        public SignatureMethod SignatureMethod { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Reference")]
        public Reference Reference { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "KeyIdentifier")]
    public class KeyIdentifier
    {

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "EncodingType")]
        public string EncodingType { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ValueType")]
        public string ValueType { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "SecurityTokenReference")]
    public class SecurityTokenReference
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "KeyIdentifier")]
        public KeyIdentifier KeyIdentifier { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "KeyInfo")]
    public class KeyInfo
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SecurityTokenReference")]
        public SecurityTokenReference SecurityTokenReference { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Signature")]
    public class Signature
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SignedInfo")]
        public SignedInfo SignedInfo { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SignatureValue")]
        public string SignatureValue { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "KeyInfo")]
        public KeyInfo KeyInfo { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ds")]
        public string Ds { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Security")]
    public class Security
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Signature")]
        public Signature Signature { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "wsse")]
        public string Wsse { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "wsu")]
        public string Wsu { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Header")]
    public class Header
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Security")]
        public Security Security { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "sender")]
    public class Sender
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "test")]
        public string Test { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "requestInfo")]
    public class RequestInfo
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "test")]
        public string Test { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "sender")]
        public Sender Sender { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "sessionId")]
        public string SessionId { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "data")]
    public class Data
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "test")]
        public string Test { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "requestData")]
    public class RequestData
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "data")]
        public Data Data { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "request")]
    public class Request
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "requestInfo")]
        public RequestInfo RequestInfo { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "requestData")]
        public RequestData RequestData { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "SendMessage")]
    public class SendMessage
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "request")]
        public Request Request { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body")]
    public class Body
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SendMessage")]
        public SendMessage SendMessage { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ns2")]
        public string Ns2 { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "wsu")]
        public string Wsu { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [MessageContract(WrapperName = "Envelope", IsWrapped = true, WrapperNamespace = "")]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope")]
    public class Envelope
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Header")]
        public Header Header { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "S")]
        public string S { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "SOAP-ENV")]
        public string SOAPENV { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

IConclusionCardInfoService.cs defined like this:

```
   [ServiceContract]
    public interface IConclusionCardInfoService
    {
        [OperationContract(Action = "", ReplyAction = "")]
        [XmlSerializerFormat]
        SendMessageResponse SendMessage(Envelope request);
    }
```

ConclusionCardInfoService.svc processing the request:

```
[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]
public class ConclusionCardInfoService : IConclusionCardInfoService
{
    public SendMessageResponse SendMessage(Envelope request)
    {
    
    }
}
```

Request Body:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                       xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#gost34310-gost34311"/>
                    <ds:Reference URI="test">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#gost34311"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>test</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>
                    test
                </ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo>
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <wsse:KeyIdentifier
                                EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"
                                ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">
                            test
                        </wsse:KeyIdentifier>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <S:Body xmlns:ns2="http://bip.bee.kz/SyncChannel/v10/Types"
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
            wsu:Id="test">
        <ns2:SendMessage>
            <request>
                <requestInfo>
                    <test>test</test>
                    <sender>
                        <test>test</test>
                    </sender>
                    <sessionId>test</sessionId>
                </requestInfo>
                <requestData>
                    <data>
                        <test>test</test>
                    </data>
                </requestData>
            </request>
        </ns2:SendMessage>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I have created a new WCF project, I am initiating a request using SoapUI. Empty data is received (Body=null and Header=null). Tell me, please, what could be the problem?

Comment: The method `SendMessage` in your implementation `ConclusionCardInfoService`  is empty, and what is your binding configuration. The soap binding should be based on an HTTP binding, such as basichttpbinding.

Comment: In the `SendMessage` method, the `Envelope` data comes with empty body, header fields.  `<service behaviorConfiguration="ConclusionCardInfoServiceBehavior"         name="Service.ConclusionCardInfoService">         <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""           name="ConclusionCardInfoService" contract="Service.IConclusionCardInfoService" /> </service>`

Comment: It looks fine. Have you tested it with postman.

Comment: I tried with postman. Returns an error:
"Message with Action "" cannot be processed on the receiver's side due to ContractFilter mismatch on EndpointDispatcher"

Comment: Is it helpful for you to look at the solution of [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37480938/the-message-with-action-cannot-be-processed-at-the-receiver-due-to-a-contrac).